# Как сделать php запрос из curl

Tags: php, curl

Есть работающий запрос вида:

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=bla-bla-bla" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"bla-bla-bla2\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\"},\"priority\":10}
```

Что я делаю не так, записав его на php

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
            'method'=>"POST",
            'content' => $reqdata = http_build_query(array(
                'to' => 'bla',
                'notification' => "{\"body\":\"Yellow\"}",
                'priority' => 10,

                )),
            'header' => implode("\r\n", array(
                    "Content-Length: " . strlen($reqdata),
                    "Authorization: key=bla2",
                    "Content-Type: application/json",
                    ""
                )),
    )));
if (false !== $response = @file_get_contents("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", false, $context)) {
    $res = json_decode($response,true);
    print_r($res)
}
```

Comment: вы бы написали, что получаете-то ?

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас `strlen($reqdata)` возвращает размер контента в байтах, а не длину строки контента в символах?

Comment: @teran strlen длина в символах аски так что соответствует количеству байт.

Comment: @fens соответствует, пока кодировка однобайтная.

Comment: @teran вы путаете с mb_strlen, а strlen всегда исходит из того что 1 символ = 1 байт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://some.url/here");
$data = [
    [
        "a" => "b",
        "b" => "c"
    ],
    [
        "a" => "b",
        "b" => "c"
    ]
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
// ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Content-Type:application/json",
    "Authorization: key=bla-bla-bla"
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$res = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) можно отправлять без кодирования. `Этот параметр может быть передан как в качестве url-закодированной строки, наподобие 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...', так и в виде массива`

Comment: @Jean-Claude Не всякий сервис поймет если ты попытаешся передать то что должно быть в теле(body) запроса, через URL. И семантически получаеться глупость.

Comment: @Jean-Claude кодировать в json может быть необходимостью если сервер в теле ожидает json.

Comment: Да, спасибо, заработало!